# How to remove part of a string after last comma in PHP

Tags: php, string, substring

How to remove part of a string after last comma in PHP ?

String : `"this is a post, number 1, date 23, month 04, year 2012"`
Expected: `"this is a post, number 1, date 23, month 04"`

Comment: Use strrpos (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to search for the comma, then substring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr) and [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) would be useful

```
$until = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string.",", ","));
```

Note: edited based on comments below

Comment: **Note:** This code does not always work, e.g. if there is no comma in the string. As there is no last comma, nothing should be removed, but all is removed.

Comment: Easy fix for missing comma at the end:

 substr($string, 0, strrpos($string.",", ","));

Answer (score 4):

You want to replace the last comma and the rest, that is a comma followed by any *other* character until the end of the string.

This can be formulated as a regular expression and that pattern can be replaced via [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with an empty string:

```
$until = preg_replace('/,[^,]*$/', '', $string);
```

This is a variant of [mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862062/367456) that works in case there is no comma in the string as well.

Comment: Indeed. A regex is often better suited as it can assert and modify the string at once.

Answer (score 3):

In the first step, explode String and delete the last part in the created presentation and implode the array

```
$tokens = explode(':', $string);      // split string on :
array_pop($tokens);                   // get rid of last element
$newString = implode(':', $tokens);   // wrap back
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to this. As of now, it is just a block of code.