# How to get the sub string from the start until the second last comma?

Tags: php, string, substring

From a string like this:

```
$a = "Viale Giulio Cesare, 137, Roma, RM, Italia";
```

I need to get the string until tne penultimate comma:

```
$b = "Viale Giulio Cesare, 137, Roma";
```

How can I remove everything finding the penultimate comma?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: yes I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862048/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-after-last-comma-in-php but I need to catch penultimate comma

Comment: So... what have you *done* with that? Why didn't the answers of that question help you?

Comment: because I didn't read the answers..I was trying something by myself..not always on stackoverflow to wait

Comment: @Cloud78 *I was trying something by myself* Copy&paste your code/attempt into your question, say what output you get and what you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first get the last comma in your string with [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php). Then out of this sub string I also search the last comma, which is then the penultimate comma. With this position of the second last comma I just get the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) of the entire string.

```
echo substr($a, 0, strrpos(substr($a, 0, strrpos($a, ",")), ","));
   //^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^
   //|             |       |             |1.Returns the position of the last comma from $a
   //|             |       |2.Get the substr() from the start from $a until the last comma
   //|             |3.Returns the position of the last comma from the substring
   //|4.Get the substr from the start from $a until the position of the second last comma
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode` to convert the items to an array by splitting it on a comma. then you can modify the array using `array_splice` and `implode` the array back together to a string:

```
<?php
$a = "Viale Giulio Cesare, 137, Roma, RM, Italia";
$l = explode(',', $a);
array_splice($l, -2);
$b = implode(',', $l);
```

Not a single line, but a very straight forward solution.

Comment: *Not a single line* Well you could put all in one line, but it's always a question of readability if you write such a long line of code. (BTW: I also thought about posting this as a solution, but then I posted one with `strrpos()`; Clear and understandable explanation ✓)

Comment: Not a single *statement*, I meant. :)

Answer (score 0):

Among the many other possible solutions, you may use the following:

```
<?php
$re = "~(.*)(?:,.*?,.*)$~"; 
$str = "Viale Giulio Cesare, 137, Roma, RM, Italia"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // output: Viale Giulio Cesare, 137, Roma
?>
```